# radio button check in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my radio button , i want to get the value from the list through alert when i click the submit button , but value is not coming

`<asp:RadioButtonList ID="Titlerbl" runat="server" CssClass="tit" 
                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ValidationGroup="grt">
                        <asp:ListItem>MR</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>MS</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>DR</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>`

this is the java script

```
var radio = document.getElementById("Titlerbl").value;
 for (var j = 0; j < radio.length; j++)
 {
        if (radio[j].checked)
            alert(radio[j].value);
 }
```

Comment: Remove .value and check it i think its work

Comment: Remove `.value` from your alert

Comment: @vinoth kannan:Updated my post.ps

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML? You need UNIQUE IDs so if you generate a list of radios, their NAMES should be the same and then you can do document.getElementsByName

Comment: @mplungjan you are correct. i had finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first in your markup you are assigning the id for the container list and not for the radio buttons elements.

so the rendered HTML will look like

```
<table id="Titlerbl">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="Titlerbl_0" type="radio" name="radiolist1" value="Item 1" checked="checked">
            <label for="Titlerbl_0">Item 1</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="Titlerbl_1" type="radio" name="radiolist1" value="Item 2">
            <label for="Titlerbl_1">Item 2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

so you can do using jquery use :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var value = $('#Titlerbl input[type=radio]:checked').val();
       alert(value);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: i am using those are all in aspx page

Comment: and make sure you have included the jquery library in your page

Comment: actually i am using in aspx page. the way which said is help full in HTML page. i done that it's working

Answer (score 0):

```
var radio = document.getElementById("Titlerbl").value;
```

should be changed to

```
var radio = document.getElementById("Titlerbl");
```

Comment: if (radio[j].checked) {
            alert(radio[j].value); 
}  

you missed open and close braces after if

Comment: why do he need braces wen just one statement is there inside if condition?